# Trying to create exe file from with a script importing pygame

Tags: python, pyinstaller

this is what I get after running the exe file for my space-invaders game even with the assets folder in the dist folder. the command use to create the exe was: `pyinstaller spaceinvaders.py --onefile --noconsole`

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNRM0.png)

Comment: Do you have pygame installed on the system that you want build the file on? Check by using: `pip install pygame`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation.

> Helping PyInstaller Find Modules
>
> Extending the Path If Analysis
> recognizes that a module is needed, but cannot find that module, it is
> often because the script is manipulating sys.path. The easiest thing
> to do in this case is to use the --paths option to list all the other
> places that the script might be searching for imports:
>
> pyi-makespec --paths=/path/to/thisdir 
> --paths=/path/to/otherdir myscript.py
>
> These paths will be noted in the spec file in the pathex argument. They will be added to
> the current sys.path during analysis.

Try to add path to that module and see if it will work after.